# Simple Custom Block

Tags: blocks

So I am trying to create a block to list the cities of the scrapyards in the system and i've followed some tutorial and i'm not even getting the block to show up in the list.

I have dir created at: `/sites/all/modules/list_city` and inside that I have the necessary .info and .module files.

The info file contains this:

```
name = List City Module
description = List the scrapyard cities
core = 7.x
```

And the module file contains this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Declare what blocks are provided by this module.
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function list_city_block_info(){
  $blocks = array();
    $blocks['list_city'] = array(
      'info' => t('My Custom Block'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Define what our block is going to look like.
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function list_city_block_view($block_key){
  $block = array();
    if($block_key == 'list_city'){
      $block['subject'] = t('Marty McFly Countdown');
      $block['content'] = t('Marty will arrive in ').(strtotime("2015-10-21")-time()).t(' seconds.');
    }
  return $block;
}
?>
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The tutorial says it should show up in the lost of blocks but i'm not seeing it.

Also how could I go on to just list `field_city` of the scrapyard node.

Linking me to some page won't help much because at the minute i've looked at 10+ websites with tutorials on how to create blocks and i'm having no luck at all

EDIT: I've looked at a simpler tutorial and i'm now trying to use this updated code

Comment: Try to clear cache.

Comment: You have info and configure, but where is [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)?!

Comment: Btw for examples check:https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

Comment: Maybe a silly question but did you enable the module?

Comment: Or as an alternative, have you considered making a simple Views block?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

listcity.info

```
name = List City Module
description = List the scrapyard cities
core = 7.x
```

listcity.module

```
/**
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/
function listcity_block_info() {
  $blocks['listcity'] = array(
    'info' => t('List City'),
  );
return $blocks;
}
```

Make sure that you enable the module. (I've forgotten to do this before)

In your code sample there is a closing php tag ?> This shouldn't be in the module file.

Comment: If I could comment on your question I would.  Really, I am just trying to help.